Realization of Surface code, can an eigenvalue of -1 be taken?
I have a question about the implementation of Surface Code. I understand that Surface Code is a stabilizer state defined by plaquette operators and vertex operators, meaning it is a state where the eigenvalues of the plaquette and vertex operators are 1.
However, according to this documentSurface code: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation, the indirect measurement of operators is implemented as shown in the following figure."
2
From this figure, the qubits around the plaquette and vertex operator can also take the eigenvalue -1 state. When actually constructing a Surface Code, is it the case that the stabilizer eigenvalue is not strictly 1, but that the eigenvalue -1 is also allowed?

Yes. The measured stabilizer value doesn't really matter as long as you perform the measurement and record the measurement value. This is because the codespace defined by all +1 eigenvalue of stabilizers has the same structure as another space defined by, e.g., all -1 eigenvalue.
Besides, the conclusion will not only apply to surface code, but to every stabilizer code when you wanna prepare the logical state with this kind of indrect syndrome measurement.

Thank you very much. I learned a lot.
